# Задача про Центр тяжести

Tags: c, c++11, структуры, struct

В программе необходимо найти центр тяжести системы.Ответ необходимо выводить с точностью в 15 значащих цифр.Программа легкая, мои тесты проходит, но в тестирующей системе проходит 0 тестов, в чем может быть проблема? В типах?

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    typedef long long ll;
    struct st {
        int x,y;
    };
    st a[100];
    int main() {
        int n;
        double s1,s2;
        cin >>n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cin >> a[i].x >> a[i].y;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            s1 = s1 + a[i].x;
            s2 = s2 + a[i].y;
            }

            cout <<s1/n<<" "<<s2/n<< "\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А у вас 15 значащих цифр выводится?

Comment: ну double же, должно выводится

Comment: Ваша программа тоже должна тесты проходить, но не проходит

Comment: И да, зачем использовать double для s1 и s2, если там только суммирование целых? typedef тоже не нужен, он не применяется...

Comment: все тесты не могут быть с выводом 15 цифр после запятой

Comment: Почему не могут? Могут...

Comment: А можно что-то более конструктивное =?

Comment: Если вы сами не хотите проверить, реально ли ваша программа удовлетворяет условиям задачи - нельзя.

Comment: Мало ли, что может быть не так. Например, в тестирующей программе координаты точек могут быть не целыми.

Comment: Они целые по условию

Comment: std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << (s1 / n) << " " << (s2 / n) << "\n";

Comment: И складывать лучше всё-таки целые, а приводить к double непосредственно при делении.

Comment: @Croessmah для std::setprecision(15)  нужно какую-то библиотеку подключать?

Comment: Включить заголовочный файл <iomanip>

Comment: Теперь даже на небольших числах выводит не то,что нужно

Comment: @JuliaPonomareva - добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос пример входных данных с ожидаемым и получаемым выводом

Comment: У вас `s1` и `s2` не инициализируются нулём перед использованием.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы найти [геометрический центр конечного множества точек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA), можно вычислить их арифметическое среднее.

Если забыть о переполнении суммы для целых чисел или точности суммирования для чисел с плавающей точкой, то прямолинейно среднее найти:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n; //NOTE: assume valid input

  // find arithmetic mean of given 2D points
  long cx = 0, cy = 0;
  for (int x, y, i = 0; i < n && (std::cin >> x) && (std::cin >> y); ++i) {
    cx += x;
    cy += y;
  }

  // print 15 significant digits
  std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(14)
            << (cx / (double) n) << ' '
            << (cy / (double) n) << '\n';
}
```

Обратите внимание, `std::setprecision` определяет количество цифр после запятой, что отличается от количества значащих цифр, поэтому научная нотация для вывода используется, чтобы получить именно нужное количество значащих цифр.

[Пример](https://ideone.com/s728tJ):

```bsh
$ c++ *.cc && echo $'2\n1 2\n3 4' | ./a.out
2.00000000000000e+00 3.00000000000000e+00
```